# JQuery - Scrolling list, increase font-size gradually

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, siblings, slideup

```
<div id="wrap">
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
</ul>
```

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  function scroll() {
    $('#wrap ul li:first').slideUp(function() {
      $(this).show().parent().append(this);
    });
  }
  setInterval(scroll, 1000);
});
```

This is basically the action I want, but I also want to add a fadeout to the top item as the slideUp is performed, AND the font size of the following item to gradually increase in size as it is moved up to top position. 
I haven't been able to figure out how unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I know I am a little bit late, but you can always try this as well**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var size = ['40px', '30px', '20px', '10px']

  function scroll() {
    renderSize();
    $('#wrap ul li:first').fadeOut('slow', function() {
      $(this).slideUp(function() {
        $(this).show().parent().append(this);
        renderSize()
      });
    })
  }

  function renderSize() {
    $('#wrap ul li').each(function(i) {
      $(this).css('font-size', size[i])
    })
  }
  
  renderSize()
  setInterval(scroll, 1000);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrap">
  <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**If you do like this you get a much smother scroll**

```js
    var size = [40, 30, 20, 10]

    function renderSize() {
      $('#wrap ul li').each(function(i) {
        $(this).css('font-size', size[i])
      })
    }

    function scroll() {
      $('#wrap ul li:first').animate({
        fontSize: "0"
      }, 500, function() {
        $(this).show().parent().append(this);
      }).animate({
        fontSize: size[3] + "px"
      }, 500)

      $('#wrap ul li').each(function(i) {
        i++;
        reSize(i);
      })
    }

    function reSize(i) {
      i++;
      var j = i - 2;
      $('#wrap ul li:nth-child(' + i + ')').animate({
        fontSize: size[j] + "px",
      }, 500)
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
      renderSize()
      setInterval(scroll, 1000);
    })
```

```css
ul {
  height: 110px;
  overflow: hidden;
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrap">
  <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: @oceansmoving I have updated my code and added a smother version of the scroll. Almost like the example you included.

Answer (score 2):

From your question, I understood that you want to increase the `font-size`  gradually.

Use **`siblings()`**

```
$('#wrap ul li:first').slideUp(function() {
      //Append item
      $(this).show().parent().append(this);
      //Change css for first item.
      $('#wrap ul li:eq(0)')
        .css('font-size', '42px')
        .siblings()      // siblings will give others
        .css('font-size', '36px');
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function scroll() {
    $('#wrap ul li:first').slideUp(function() {
      $(this).show().parent().append(this);
      $('#wrap ul li:eq(0)')
           .css('font-size', '42px')
           .siblings()
           .css('font-size', '36px');
    });
  }
  setInterval(scroll, 1000);
});
```

```css
li{
 font-size: 36px  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrap">
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Not exacly. I'd like the top item to be slightly bigger than the rest and the adjacent item to gradually increase up to that size while moving up.

Comment: Is everything ok ?

Comment: I see now that my description could be better. 
The top item should have a font size of, let's say, 42 and the rest of the list 36. When the second item is sliding up to top position I'd want it to gradually increase from 36 to 42. When that same item is appended to the list (bottom position), it should return to 36 again, and so on.

Comment: @oceansmoving No problem, See now again I've updated my answer and example.

Answer (score 0):

How can I make the top item also slide up as the rest are, instead of staying fixed in the background to make the slide look more seamless?

Pretty much like this:
http://buildinternet.com/project/totem/
Except called by setInterval instead of clicking on next